# Find all valid combinations for a four digit clock

Tags: combinatorics

So, if we have a four digit clock $HH:MM$ how can we find all the possible valid combinations? One way is to see that that the clock is made of two groups of numbers ($HH$ and $MM$) and then multiply the combinations of the two. Namely,
$ 24\cdot60 = 1440 $

My question is: How can we derive the same result considering each digit individually instead of grouping them. Is it possible?

EDIT: Although @ArsenBerk's reply answers the question I was thinking of a solution that takes all the possibilities assuming no restrictions and then apply some pruning to remove the overcounting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the formatting is as $H_2H_1:M_2M_1$. For the minutes part, that is easy because without any restrictions, we can say that $M_2$ has $6$ options, namely $0,1,2,3,4,5$ and $M_1$ has $10$ options, namely $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. So we have $6 \cdot 10 = 60$ possible combinations for the minutes part.

When it comes to hours part, we have a slight restriction when $H_2 = 2$. For $H_2 = 0$ and $H_2 = 1$, notice that without any restrictions, $H_1$ has $10$ options for each. But for $H_2 =2$, since $H_2H_1$ cannot exceed $23$, $H_1$ has only $4$ options, namely $0,1,2,3$. Therefore in hours part, there are $2\cdot10+4 = 24$ possible combinations. So your result follows.

Comment: I have edited the question, if nobody replies in the near future I will accept your solution. Thank you for your time!